# Additional fields to the cover page of a CRAN manual

Tags: r, package

The [XML package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/XML.pdf) contains an additional field, `Note:`,  to the cover page of the CRAN manual.  I tried adding `Note: blah blah` to a package manual (I put this in the `Description` file)but it was not created with Note.  How can one add additional fields to the cover page of a manual (or maybe this is restricted and a bad idea)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this at the moment, but it looks like the "Note" line was added to [the `DESCRIPTION` file](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#The-DESCRIPTION-file).

Comment: Josh I'm sorry for not stating that above (I'll remedy that) but I did put it in the Description file.

Comment: Never mind I messed up the package I was testing it on.  Man I feel like a ding dong.